# UIApplication.shared.open only works with https

Tags: swift, url, uiapplication, urlopen

I trying to open url with UIApplication.shared.open function but i'm little bit confused because its not working for [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) and its working for https://www.google.com.

```
struct GetIsoCode: View {
    @State var titile = "www.google.com"
    var body: some View {
        Text(titile)
            .onTapGesture {
                let urlS = URL(string:titile)
                if let url = urlS {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(url) { (response) in
                        print(response)
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

First Use case:

Input url:

> www.google.com

Output:

> Failed to open URL [www.google.com](http://www.google.com): Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 "invalid input parameters" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=invalid input parameters, _LSLine=234, _LSFunction=-[_LSDOpenClient openURL:options:completionHandler:]}

Second Use case:

Input:

> https://www.google.com

Result: It's working fine.

Can someone please explain to me how to show google from both links, I've tried to implement by above but no results yet.

Comment: This has nothing to do with SwiftUI, since `UIApplication` is a pure `UIKit` type and you're having an issue with `UIApplication`, not SwiftUI.

Comment: `www.google.com` is a URL that has no scheme. `http://www.google.com` is a URL with the scheme `http`. `https://www.google.com` is a URL with the scheme `https`. `openURL()` requires its URLs to have schemes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs say:

> UIKit supports many common schemes, including the http, https, tel,
> facetime, and mailto schemes.
>
> Use this method to open the specified resource. If the specified URL
> scheme is handled by another app, iOS launches that app and passes the
> URL to it. (Launching the app brings the other app to the foreground.)
> If no app is capable of handling the specified scheme, the completion
> handler is called with the success parameter set to NO.
>
> To determine whether an app is installed that is capable of handling
> the URL, call the canOpenURL: method before calling this one

1. Which *URL scheme* would the string "www.google.com" be?
2. Call canOpenURL first, before calling open(url:)